# Is it possible to create a submenu from the top Tab Bar in tvOS?

Tags: ios, uitabbar, tvos, television, apple-tv

Does anyone know if there is built in functionality of UITabBarController to achieve a submenu that drops down after you highlight a section in the main top Tabbed navigation bar?  This is for tvOS.

[image: Top Bar protoype]